# Javascript onpaste not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the html and Javascript below I count the number of characters entered in an input field and limit them to 30. I also show a counter to the user.

The counter changes its value on this events: `onfocus`, `onKeyDown`, `onKeyUp`, `onpaste`.

I can't get `onpaste` to work. The counter changes value when user pastes using "CTRL V" but not when pasting using mouse / right click. What am I doing wrong?

**Jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ow3ubgp0/

**HTML:**

```
<input readonly type="text" name="countdown1" size="5" value="30" />

<input type="text" id="my_text_input" name="my_text_input" onfocus="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onpaste="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try listening to the `oninput` event. Your code looks needlessly redundant though—you should consider using event handlers instead of inline JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/xdcxafay/14/).

`oninput` : Execute a JavaScript when a user writes something in an  field.

```
<form>
        <input readonly type="text" name="countdown1" size="5" value="30" />

        <input onfocus="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onpaste="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);"
    oninput="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" type="text" id="my_text_input" name="my_text_input" /></input>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, oninput was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

hi plz check with following code

I hope it helps

```
<html>
<form>
<input readonly type="text" name="countdown1" size="5" value="30" />

<input type="text" id="my_text_input" name="my_text_input" onfocus="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onpaste="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" onChange="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);" oninput="limitText(this.form.my_text_input,this.form.countdown1,30);"/>
</form>
<script>
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Omited the form tag from the post, but this is not the problem. Please see the Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ow3ubgp0/. Counter does not update when pasting with the mouse.

Comment: Still nothing - counter should update as sun as I clisk paste and text is pasted into the input.

Answer (score 0):

- ### function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) { if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) { limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum); } else { limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length; } }

the limitField.value.length is zero. it is the value of previous value of paste.

so it is less than limitNum forever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that event **onpaste** is fired just before the DOM field actually has the new value. One trick is to use a small delay to get the real paste:

```
<input onpaste="setTimeout( function(){alert(event.target.value);},10)" />
```